# Acronym with gershayims above letters

Tags: synagogue, writing-printing

In the [Alte-Neu (Old-New) Synagogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_New_Synagogue) in Prague, there are several inscriptions on the wall (see [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C#/media/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:Old_New_Synagogue_SOUTH.JPG)) - for example this (this one is said to be an acronym of: אך טוב לישראל סלה):

> [image: אטליס with gerhsayims above all letters but yod]

Is it semantically correct to write it with U+059E HEBREW ACCENT GERSHAYIM marks, i.e.:

> א֞ט֞ל֞יס֞

*(might not be rendered correctly in all browsers, but it's a different issue)*

Or is there a more correct way how to represent it?

*(I should also note that these are not to represent numbers/years, which are in the same synagogue marked with dots above)*

Comment: That letter at the end looks an awful lot like a ם (mem sofit) rather than a ס (samech)...

Comment: Hi @mykhal and welcome to Mi Yodeya - could you perhaps provide some more contextual information for us please? What Synagogue are you referring to? where are these inscriptions etc.

Comment: @Dov it's אלטנוישול

Comment: That's in Prague right?

Comment: @Dov Yeah, [here's](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C#/media/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:Old_New_Synagogue_SOUTH.JPG) a pic of the wall. And I guess that really is a samech.

Comment: @Harel13 samech or mem sofit… never mind, this is a different issue as well – the meaning of the inscription is not the main topic of my question…

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by editing a font to "straighten out" the gershayim, but I don't recommend this implementation for public consumption, since this is not the purpose of this Unicode character. I did this for a project: I "straightened out" a geresh into a (single acute accent) stress marker, but it's not a method I'd release.

Some longer-term solutions that use the Unicode characters as intended:

- Create (or edit) a font with ligatures for Hebrew letter + Hebrew punctuation gershayim (U+05F4).
- Alternatively, make a combined glyph for Hebrew letter + combining double acute accent (U+030B).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, gershayim or quotation marks are used somewhat like italics in English. They are universally used to point out an abbreviation, and often to point out a pun (notably in the Chida's works). Generally there is only one per word, before the last letter, but occasionally you see more than one per word. See for example Bava Kama 22a in Rabbeinu Chananel (in older editions of Gemara.)

Comment: Tantzevah is another example, as it is often written out ת"נ"צ"ב"ה" rather than תנצב"ה on most matzeivot. See also siddurim which only print the final passuk of Tehillim once, which often print the second as כ"ה"ת"י"ה"

Comment: The OP was about how to represent this on the computer.